# Qt3D "qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig" Warning

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt3d

Ubuntu 18.04.1 operating system, QT version 5.12

After starting the program that shows the 3D window, the console is written the following warning:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (8 8 8 0)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 8 8 0)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 8 0)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 0)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 0)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 0)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (8 8 8 0)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 8 8 0)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 8 0)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 0)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 0)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 0)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (8 8 8 0)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 8 8 0)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 8 0)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 0)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 0)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 0)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (8 8 8 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 8 8 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 8 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (8 8 8 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 8 8 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 8 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (8 8 8 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 8 8 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 8 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 8)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (1 1 1 8
```

Perhaps this information may help answer the question:

```
sudo ldconfig -p | grep -i gl.so
[sudo] password for ilya: 
    libwayland-egl.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
    libcogl.so.20 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.20
    libOpenGL.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so.0
    libOpenGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so
    libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
    libGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
    libEGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1
    libEGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so
```

Comment: I have the same warnings under Arch linux. The problem start to appear after upgrading from Qt 5.11 to Qt 5.12. However everything works well.

Comment: I have the exact same problem at closing the application. Appeared after updating from Qt version `5.11.1` to `5.12.3`

Comment: I also have the same warning, on slackware. Not sure what caused it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using `QSurfaceFormat`? I had the same issue and uncommenting `QSurfaceFormat.setSamples` helped to resolve the issue:

```
QSurfaceFormat fmt;
//fmt.setSamples(4);
fmt.setVersion(3, 0);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(fmt);
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: `export QT_XCB_GL_INTEGRATION=none`

ps: some people mentioned that it's likely to happen with remote desktop/vnc (in my case it's a vnc connection to aws ec2 instance).